# how to open routes with laravel

Tags: laravel

i'm just finished to install laravel 5.7 in my linux mint 18.3 and 
when i run the server with php artisan serve and later i open localhost i can't not see the first page...
It say 'Page not found' i do not understand why happen this.
i can not see any route.

I modified the phpconfig file with this

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and i turn on the rewrite php module with

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But still not working.

Comment: What's inside your `routes.php`? By the way, if you want to check routes, go `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Is your Laravel app inside `www`? Not inside `www/other-folder`?

Comment: the routes exists, but i can't see the default 'view' of laravel.

Comment: You have method which handles that route you want to access? Or it's with closure?

Comment: it says closure in every route

Comment: +--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI      | Name | Action  | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /        |      | Closure | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user |      | Closure | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD | nueva    |      | Closure | web          |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+---------

Comment: I mean your `routes.php`

Comment: Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

This is the route by default but i can't see his view

Comment: Check Apache settings, I've written above

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to run off the `public` folder:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/public

<Directory /var/www/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```